# How i can get access for '~/Applications' of iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, python-3.x, pythonista

I'm trying to enter to this folder using:

```
import os  
location=os.chdir('/Applications')  
for file in os.listdir(location):  
     print(file)
```

RETURN:
 'Opesation not permitted'

When i run this, in the pythonista app, appears an alert message

But when alternately i run it but with the base root file directory, it pritns me all folders

```
import os  
location=os.chdir('/')  
for file in os.listdir(location):
    print(file)
```

RETURN:
  .file
  .mb
  Applications
  Developer
  Library
  System
  bin
  cores
  dev
  etc
  private
  sbin
  tmp
  usr
  var

Comment: I guess you don't have read permission on that folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

> For security purposes, an iOS app’s interactions with the file system are limited to the directories inside the app’s sandbox directory.

You should have access only to certain folders

> During installation of a new app, the installer creates a number of container directories for the app inside the sandbox directory. Each container directory has a specific role.

This is your only working area

> **iOS apps always run in a sandbox**